# How to compute kolmogorov complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: space-complexity

Suppose for various input strings an algorithm generates binary string with same number of 0's and 1's. The output for two different input strings may or may not be the same. Can we say anything about the space complexity of the algorithm?

Answer (score 5):

The question isn't quite right.

Kolmogorov complexity K(x) doesn't apply to programs, it applies to a string x. 
More specifically, the Kolmogorov complexity of a string x is the minimum program length needed to compute a particular string x.

It has been formally proven that one can't compute the Kolmogorov complexity of a string. In practice, you can approximate via an upper bound.

The following paper by Ferbus-Zanda and Griorieff gives you the theory http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3201

An intuitive way of thinking about such an approximate upper bound is to consider the length of a compression program that can decompress to a particular string.

Applying this to your problem, the string you describe is a random binary one, doubled. The input string acts a seed for the random number generator.

Ignoring the kolmogorov complexity part of your question, and just looking at space complexity (ie. memory footprint) aspect as @templatetypedef did, the criteria you mention are so loose that all you can say is that the lower space bound for the algorithm is O(1) and the upper bound O(n), where n is the output.

Comment: It should be pointed out that in fact there exists a notion of "Kolmogorov complexity of a function". It was proposed by Schnorr. Check out
"Schnorr С. P, Optimal Gödel numberings, Proc. IF IP congress 71 (1971), v. 1, 56-58" and "Schnorr С. P., Optimal enumerations and optimal Gödel numberings, M athem atical System s Theory (now Theory of Computing Systems), v. 8 (1975), no. 2, 182-191"

Comment: "one can't compute the Kolmogorov complexity of a string" I don't think that's quite right.  I believe the proof is that (basically because of undecidability) you can't make an algorithm that will compute the Kolmogorov complexity of any/all arbitrary strings.  There are many strings whose complexity CAN be computed, I think, though - for instance, if your language includes an instruction which, uninitialized, outputs e.g. "0", and an empty program does not output "0", you know its complexity is 1.  I don't know how fast we get into uncertainty, though, for larger strings and normal languages.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so. Consider the algorithm "print 01," which requires space Θ(1), and the algorithm "double the length of the input string, then print 01," which requires space Θ(n). Both algorithms meet the criteria you've provided, so just given those criteria you can't say anything about the space complexity of the algorithm.

Hope this helps!